# Automate addition of elif statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to automate the addition of elif statements in a for loop in python (because it's exhausting to type out every single elif statement, not to mention possibly making it slower)... Something like this:

```
 for i, j in zip(range(len(keys())), keys()):
    elif act_type <= (1 + i) * screen_h:
        press(j)
        print("Agent has pressed " + j)
```

How should I go about doing this? I really don't want to have to type every elif statement. The keys function returns an about-60-items list, by the way...

EDIT: Act_type is an integer created by the agent, screen_h is the horizontal screen size divided by the size of the array... The press function is just a call to press that key using pyautogui.press.

Here's what I'm wanting to do uncurled...:

```
if act_type <= screen_h:
    press('command')
elif act_type <= screen_h * 2:
    press('up')
elif act_type <= screen_h * 3:
    press('left')
elif act_type <= screen_h * 4:
    press('right')
elif act_type <= screen_h * 5:
    press('down')
elif act_type <= screen_h * 6:
    ...
```

Comment: That is absolutely the wrong (and impossible) way to approach the problem. Try explaining exactly what you need the code to do and I'm sure someone will give you a better option. In other words, what are the other `elif` tests and what is the meaning of the variables?

Comment: Note that `zip(range(len(X)), X)` can be more clearly expressed as `enumerate(X)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need dynamically generated `elif` clauses; just a single `if` statement in the body of the `for` loop. Use `break` to terminate the `for` loop early, to mirror the situation when an `elif` clause applies in a single `if` statement.

```
for i, key in enumerate(keys(), start=1):
    if act_type <= i * screen_h:
        press(key)
        print("Agent has pressed key".format(key))
        break
```

Comment: I don't think I want to terminate the for loop. But I'll test this out...

Comment: If you don't `break`, this will execute `press` et al. for *every* value of `i` that makes `(1+i) * screen_h` larger than `act_type`, not just the *first* one (which is what `if .. elif .. elif .. elif ...` would do).

Comment: (Note in the updated answer, I used `start=1` to avoid the addition in the body of the loop.)